# Add more servers to SP2016 Single Server Farm

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-on-prem, production, multiple-farms

We have a SP 2016 single server farm where SharePoint and SQL are installed in the same machine.

only 1 site collection exists in the farm and due to recent increase in team size, we are facing performance and site availability issues.

I would like to increase the servers in the farm.

What is the best/recommended approach?

Comment: MS has good doc around this... https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/install/add-a-server-to-a-sharepoint-server-2016-farm

Answer (score 0):

Vaghasia provided the best doc to perform the process of adding servers. And just to note, i assume you are using single server farm role for now.

> The concept of server roles has changed staring with SharePoint Server
>   2016. You can't add a server to a farm if the farm currently contains a server assigned to the "Single Server Farm" role.

You will need to change to new roles for your server. So make sure you have read this [article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/install/overview-of-minrole-server-roles-in-sharepoint-server) and this [article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/managing-a-minrole-server-farm-in-sharepoint-server-2016)